# Conjuction big sign

Tags: convex-analysis, symbolic-computation, conjunctive-normal-form

I have a difficult time understand how [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwFz4.jpg): [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwFz4.jpg] this large conjunction and disjunction symbols relates to that simpler, same conjunction expression.What these big conjunction and disjunction symbols mean?

Comment: Thank you for your explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\overline{\bigvee_{i=1}^n} p_i = \overline{p_1 \vee p_2 \vee \cdots \vee p_n}$$ and similarly $$\bigwedge _{i=1}^n \overline{p_i} = \overline{p_1} \wedge \overline{p_2} \wedge \cdots \wedge \overline{p_n}$$ 
so (1a) is a generalisation of (1) to $n$ terms

Answer (score 1):

$\bigwedge_{i=1}^np_i$ means $p_1 \wedge p_2 \wedge \ldots \wedge p_n$ and
$\bigvee_{i=1}^np_i$ means $p_1 \vee p_2 \vee \ldots \vee p_n$. (And the overlines $\overline{p_i}$ etc. mean logical negation.)